# Avoiding 100 item limit in the Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a project for which we are storing user profile photos in Sitecore. Our user base is going to be integrated with LDAP (meaning that we will have tens of thousands of users, if not more), and profiles will be created the first time a user logs in. Users will be able to change their profile photos later, and we have a customized Sitecore Profile, which has a property to store the ID of the profile photo media item.

What I am trying to do is figure out a way to avoid breaking the 100 item limit and store the photos in the Sitecore Media Library. We do not want to use item buckets, and we want to leverage Sitecore caching, so storing the images externally is out. I was thinking about a ten-level deep folder structure based on the username, but that is a bit dirty.

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help?

Thank you, in advance.

*Sitecore 6.6*

Comment: Could I ask why you don't want to use item buckets?  If you don't, you will just end up building a cheap version of the same functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Item Buckets module is no longer supported nor available for download on the marketplace; they decided to re-focus their efforts on the integration with Sitecore 7.

Comment: Zachary I update my answer. Hope it fits better to your needs now

Comment: I didn't realize that they removed the download.  I guess that is because the upgrade to Sitecore 7 is so easy, it's better to just do that.  If you are on 6.6. update 5 or later, there aren't even any DB changes.  It's just an update package.

Comment: I completely agree, but the caveat is that the client must be willing to do it, and when the client is a large corporation there tends to be all sorts of security screenings and investigation (on their end) before they can approve any software upgrades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoiding breaking the 100 children limit is a very good practice and you should follow this for sure.

To achieve this in your scenario you definitely need some kind of folder structure. Creating such a kind of structure is not fun. You can automate it by adding you event handler to `item:created` event and move the newly created item automatically.

I've written quick code that should check if the current folder contains max 50 items and if not it tries to create additional folders with a single char as a name recursively and move the item to the folder.

You wrote that you're storing reference as ID so moving the item will not break reference.

Please have in my that I haven't tested the code so it might need tweaking.

```xml
<event name="item:created">
  <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ProfilePhotoHandler, My.Assembly" method="OnItemCreated" />
</event>
```

```cs
protected void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ItemCreatedEventArgs eventArgs = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatedEventArgs;

    if (eventArgs == null || eventArgs.Item == null)
        return;
    Item item = eventArgs.Item;

    if (item == null
        || !item.Paths.IsMediaItem
        || !item.Paths.FullPath.Contains("/profile-images/")
        || item.TemplateID.ToString() == "{FE5DD826-48C6-436D-B87A-7C4210C7413B}")

        // we want to move only media items in profile-images and not media folders
        return;

    string guid = item.ID.ToShortID().ToString();

    MoveItemToProperDirectory(guid, item, item.Parent, 0);
}

private void MoveItemToProperDirectory(string guid, Item item, Item folder, int level)
{
    if (folder.Children.Count < 1)
    {
        if (item.Parent.ID != folder.ID)
        {
            item.MoveTo(folder);
        }
        return;
    }

    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        // take next letter from the hash or random char if the hash is too short
        string newSubfolderName = (level < guid.Length)
                                        ? guid[level].ToString()
                                        : ('a' + new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(24)).ToString();

        Item subfolder = folder.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == newSubfolderName);
        if (subfolder == null)
        {
            // create new Media Folder and move the item there
            subfolder = folder.Add(newSubfolderName, new TemplateID(ID.Parse("{FE5DD826-48C6-436D-B87A-7C4210C7413B}")));
        }
        MoveItemToProperDirectory(guid, item, subfolder, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that we have tens of thousands of users.

Comment: Oh I understood that the problem is with number of images not with the number of users. Let me try to think about other solution.

Comment: Great! I think that I am going to go in a similar direction to this one, but may implement it using an `item:saved` handler and the `Guid` of the item (breaking apart the `Guid` and taking the first 3 character pairs - should give a few hundred thousand possible `Guid`s). For safety, I am also going to implement a check similar to yours, to make sure that the number of items in each folder does not exceed 99. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: I've improved slightly my answer - added check for media folder template and use short item id instead of hash that contained invalid characters.

Answer (score 2):

If somehow an update is not an option, you could consider the following:
The images are not used by content editors, thus from the content editor, the items are not used.
This makes it possible to hide the node that contains the images, just like the buckets do.
Combining this with a folder structure (created during import, or in the handles) makes a good solution.